# Conditional update through a parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two update statements. See below. They both updates the TOOL_BOX table.
I want to parameterize update and combine the two update logic into a single update statement base on the following parameterized conditions.

1. If PARAMETER table key='Y', then run the below Update 1.
2. If PARAMETER table key='N', then run Update 2.

Update 1:Updates a subset of the data to 1

```
Update tool_box tab1 set col1 = 1
where exists
(select 1 
from
   (select object_name
         max(object_id) object_id
    from tool_box
   group by object_name
   ) x
where x.object_id=tab1.object_id
)
```

Update 2: Updates entire col1 to 1.

```
Update tool_box tab1 set col1 = 1
where exists
(select 1 
from dual)
```

Comment: @nbk oracle database

Comment: where is "parameter" ? where is "key" ?

Comment: Create a procedure that accepts a parameter. Based on it, use IF-THEN-ELSE and execute one of these two UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this modification to your first update should be enough to cover second one:

```
Update tool_box tab1 set col1 = 1
where exists
(select 1 
from
   (select object_name
         max(object_id) object_id
    from tool_box
   group by object_name
   ) x
where x.object_id=tab1.object_id
)
or exists (select 1 from parameter where key = 'N');
```

Comment: That's what I came up with as well. For some reason, when the key='N' in the parameter table making the OR exists statement empty, the query runs forever. If I run the two conditions separately, it's instant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PARAMETER  is a binding parameter:

```
Update tool_box tab1 set col1 = 1
where (exists
(select 1 
from
   (select object_name
         max(object_id) object_id
    from tool_box
   group by object_name
   ) x
where x.object_id=tab1.object_id
) )
or :PARAMETER = 'N'
```